# MySql - Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint if fulltext index added

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, full-text-indexing, fulltext-index

I have a database and i took up a dump using `--no-data`.
I am trying to import that DB structure in an empty DB.

I am ignoring other queries, following the queries I am trying to execute,

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ACTIVITY`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `ACTIVITY` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  `ACTIVITY_BY_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENTITY_TYPE` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, -- this
  `ACTIVITY_TYPE` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL, -- this
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_ACTIVITY_TO_USER_idx` (`ACTIVITY_BY_ID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `FK_FULL_TEXT_ACTIVITY_TYPE` (`ACTIVITY_TYPE`), 
  FULLTEXT KEY `FK_FULL_TEXT_ENTITY_TYPE` (`ENTITY_TYPE`), 
  ...
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ACTIVITY_TO_USER` FOREIGN KEY (`ACTIVITY_BY_ID`) REFERENCES `USER` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**The above code fails** saying `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

It should work as foreign_key_checks is set to 0.

Below is the sql for importing `USER` table. However this sql is being executed later.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `USER`;

/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `USER` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ..
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4070 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I execute the `USER` script first and then `ACTIVITY`, it works, otherwise it does not.

**The lines I marked with `--this` for the table `ACTIVITY` is causing the issue. If I remove the two lines, code works fine.**

***Why a fulltext index create a foreign key issue?***

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a bug in mysql community server version `5.7.8-rc`.

We upgraded to `5.7.20` and it got solved.